# How to avoid virtual functions in C when designing an Entity System

Tags: c, c++11, virtual-functions, game-development, entity-system

I want to design an entity system for my game using just C and a small subset of C++. Many people do this using inheritance, but I stumbled across *tagged unions* and learned that you can achieve a similar result this way, because virtual functions are slow for games(so I heard from Casey Mouratori and Jon Blow, two game devs from which I draw a lot of inspiration).

```
struct Unit {
   int type;
   int hp;
   union {
      struct {
        int kingID; 
      } soldier_data;

      struct {
        string name;
      } king_data;
   };
}
```

Jon Blow avoids virtual functions using some features from his new language Jai which is not yet released, so the example above is my only idea.

For example I could write only one Update function and use the type to differentiate between entities. This would be a very large function but hey, we avoid virtual functions.

The things is my game contains lets say soldiers and trees. Trees are static and do mostly nothing, so I would write another lighter struct for trees entities, to save some memory, and use a unions to store different types of trees:

```
struct TreeEntity {    
      Texture* texture;    
      union {
        struct {
           int height;
        } pineTree_data;
        struct {
           string name;
        } coconutTree_data;
   }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is what if both soldiers and trees are *clickable*?
If I had used inheritance I would simple have a function Entity* selectEntity(), and check the instance type after, but with my approach I'm a kind of lost.

Is my approach bad? Should I stick to virtual functions or there is a way to handle this?

Comment: *"virtual functions are slow for games"* This is likely taken out of context. Virtual functions are essentially function pointers, and **very fast**. They are often the most performant option *compared to alternatives you need to achieve same functionality*.

Comment: _a small subset of C++_: so you compile with a C++ compiler? Please clarify and add the C++ tag if it applies.

Comment: Your approach with creating a "variant" union with enum + data will introduce extra branches that weren't in the alternative that uses function pointers for inheritance. Because each time you access this "variant", you need to check "who am I?". So likely, this is a bad idea. But there's not enough context to tell, the question is too broad.

Comment: running a variant with std::visit simply replaces your virtual function call with a indexed function pointer table lookup. In assembly this should result in one more instruction. And this is only the best case if jump table generation if fully done during compile time. Doing all this handcrafted is only useful for self education. @user694733: using virtual functions results not only in using the vtable pointer jump, it also makes optimization in some cases impossible. So there is more than the call itself on overhead coast!

Comment: @Klaus Yes, of course. I was merely saying that for many problems, even in games, they are still fast enough. Many beginners can fall into trap of designing overly complex and ineffective workarounds.

Comment: *"Trees are static and do mostly nothing, so I would write another lighter struct for trees entities, to save some memory, and use a unions to store different types of trees"* I forgot to point this out: unions always reserve memory according to it's biggest member. If your goal is to save memory, you might not want to use unions!

Comment: But it makes my entities cache friendly, having an array of these fixed sized structures makes iterations very fast.

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHqFrNyLlpA&t=503s] watch the first 10 minutes if you have time

Answer (score 1):

You ask how to create a generic `Entity* selectEntity()` function which can return either a Unit* or a Tree* (or perhaps other things).

You can do it by returning a base-class pointer.  Unit and Tree inherit from Entity, and Entity can contain a small enum like:

```
enum class EntityType : uint8_t {
    Unit, Tree, // ...
};
```

If you don't want to use inheritance, you can instead just have a common initial subsequence of member variables in every type of Entity, like this:

```
struct Unit {
    EntityType type;
    // ...
};
```

This is equivalent to the inheritance version in terms of memory layout, and you could return an EntityType* from `selectEntity()`, which will actually point to the first member of a Unit or Tree.